# ! Package biblatex Error: Conflicting options (maxcitenames/mincitenames)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am new to Latex and I am using ieee style with biblatex but i want the maximum in-text citation **when i mention the authors name directly** to be as follows.

if two authors: intext citation =author A + author B +year
if more than 2 authors: intext citation = author A+et al+year

I and using maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=2 but i get this error 
! Package biblatex Error: Conflicting options(maxcitenames/mincitenames).

please see MWE for better understanding.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[style=ieee,maxbibnames=10,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,headheight=15pt,headsep=0.3in,height

@article{Dennis2014overview,
    Author = {Leung, Dennis YC and Caramanna, Giorgio},
    Date-Added = {2017-05-30 20:20:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-05-30 20:20:18 +0000},
    Journal = {Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
    Pages = {426--443},
    Publisher = {Elsevier},
    Title = {An overview of current status of carbon dioxide capture and storage technologies},
    Volume = {39},
    Year = {2014}}

@article{lasse2012public,
    Author = {Wallquist, Lasse and Seigo, Selma L'Orange and Visschers, Vivianne HM and Siegrist, Michael},
    Date-Added = {2017-05-30 20:20:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2017-05-30 20:20:18 +0000},
    Journal = {International Journal of Greenhouse Gas Control},
    Pages = {77--83},
    Publisher = {Elsevier},
    Title = {Public acceptance of CCS system elements: a conjoint measurement},
    Volume = {6},
    Year = {2012}}

\begin{document}

\textbf{example 1} As pointed out by \textcite{Dennis2014overview}, the success of deploying CCS bla bla bla bla...... A public survey by \textcite{lasse2012public} on peoples preference for bla bla bla......... 

\textbf{example 2} for this example i  just want the number to appear in the text and it works fine \cite{Dennis2014overview}. 

\end{document}
```

**for example 1: output=** As pointed out by **Leung and Caramanna[1]**, the success of deploying CCS bla bla bla bla...... A public survey by **Wallquist, Seigo, Visschers, et al [2]** showed that peoples preference for bla bla bla.........

**Desired output** As pointed out by **Leung and Caramanna (2014) [1]**, the success of deploying CCS bla bla bla bla...... A public survey by **Wallquist et al (2012) [2]** showed that peoples preference for bla bla bla.........

**for exmaple 2 the ouput is perfect.** = for this example i  just want the number to appear in the text and it works fine **[1]**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The golden rule when it comes to `min/max(bib|cite)names` is that `min(bib|cite)names` cannot be greater than `max(bib|cite)names`.

The defaults from `ieee.bbx` are

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
  maxnames = 999,
  minnames = 3,
}
```

So you can't set `max(cite|bib)names` to a value less than three without also redefining `min(cite|bib)names`.

Try

```
\usepackage[style=ieee, maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1]{biblatex}
```

This displays (probably) all authors in the bibliography (instead of your 10, but you can of course go with 10), and it uses one or two names in citations.